# How to run boost client websocket when the client is disconnected in C++?

Tags: c++, boost, websocket

I am writing a web socket for sending and receiving data to the server and below is the code, I want this code to run automatically if the server stops and starts again or if the client-side has internet issues then it should re-establish the connection on its own if the connection closed abruptly due to any issue from the server and client-side. Also, this code always goes into the catch block since the closing gives the error  `End of File`, I am a noob techie and so couldn't understand the previously answered questions.

```
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket; // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

// Sends a WebSocket message and prints the response




int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try
    {
        // Check command line arguments.
        if(argc != 4)
        {
            std::cerr <<
                "Usage: websocket <host> <port> <text>\n" <<
                "Example:\n" <<
                "    websocket echo.websocket.org 80 \"Hello, world!\"\n";
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        auto const host = argv[1];
        auto const port = argv[2];
        auto const text = argv[3];

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        net::io_context ioc;

        // These objects perform our I/O
        tcp::resolver resolver{ioc};
        websocket::stream<tcp::socket> ws{ioc};
        // Look up the domain name
        auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port,boost::asio::ip::resolver_query_base::numeric_service);

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        net::connect(ws.next_layer(), results.begin(), results.end(),ec);
        // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
        ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
            [](websocket::request_type& req)
            {
                req.set(http::field::user_agent,
                    std::string("agent"));
            }));

        // Perform the websocket handshake
        ws.handshake(host, "/");
        
        // Send the message
        ws.write(net::buffer(std::string(text)));
        // This buffer will hold the incoming message
        beast::multi_buffer buffer;
        
        // Read a message into our buffer
        ws.read(buffer);
        // The make_printable() function helps print a ConstBufferSequence
        std::cout << beast::make_printable(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
        // Close the WebSocket connection
        ws.close(websocket::close_code::normal);
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Just put a loop in your code round the try catch?

Comment: but what if it is connected already?